# Initializing 2D Array In Class Constructor in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I define a 2D array in my header file

```
char map[3][3];
```

How can I initialize the values in the class constructor like this

```
 map = {{'x', 'x', 'o'},
       {'o', 'o', 'x'},
       {'x', 'o', 'x'}};
```

Comment: Did you actually try your code?

Comment: Is this going to be a static constant array, static variable array, or class member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, there is a difference between assignment and initialization. The OP title is about initialization.

Secondly, you have not told us if your 2D array is a class member(static/non static) or a namespace variable.

-Since you mentioned about initializing it in the class constructor, I am assuming that it is a class non static member, because:

> $12.6.2/2 - "Unless the
>   mem-initializer-id names the
>   constructor’s class, a non-static data
>   member of the constructor’s class, or
>   a direct or virtual base of that
>   class, the mem-initializer is
>   ill-formed."

Further, as of C++03 the member array cannot be initialized in the constructor initializer list for the case in OP(not sure about C++0x) though.

-If your 2D array is a static member of your class, you should initialize it as you did (with a slight change), but not in the constructor. This should be done in the enclosing namespace scope once and only once in any of the translation units.

```
char (A::map)[3][3] = {{'x', 'x', 'o'}, 
       {'o', 'o', 'x'}, 
       {'x', 'o', 'x'}};
```

-Alternatively, if your 2D array is a namespace scope variable, the definition of the array should be taken out of the header file (unless it is also static) as it will cause a redefinition error and be defined and initialized once and only once in any translation unit as

```
char map[3][3] = {{'x', 'x', 'o'}, 
       {'o', 'o', 'x'}, 
       {'x', 'o', 'x'}};
```

Comment: Well, since initializing an array in an initialization list is impossible, it must be done by way of assignment in the body of the constructor.  So I would call that "initializing" even if it wasn't done upon creation of the variable.

Comment: As Scott Myers says, assignment is better than initialization for built in data types. Much easier to mantain and less error prone !!

Answer (score 1):

```
memcpy(map,"xxoooxxox",9);
```

or

```
char tmp[3][3] =
    {{'x','x','o'},
     {'o','o','x'},
     {'x','o','x'}};
memcpy(map,tmp,9);
```

Comment: `char tmp[] = "xxoooxxox"; char* map[3] = { tmp + 0, tmp + 3, tmp + 6 }; `

Comment: @rwong as soon as the tmp array is destroyed your map will have invalid pointers.

Comment: @rwong You just created a new array.  This will have no effect on the array that's part of his class.

Comment: @Michael: my answer was responding to the earlier version of PigBen's answer, which has been edited away. What I wanted to point out is that taking the address of `tmp` from `char tmp[3][3]` would not give a pointer to `char`, it would give a pointer *to pointer* to `char`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read question careful enough. None of the code works. [Chubsdad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878670#3878862) had given the answer.

Comment: @rwong Yes, it would be a pointer to a pointer, but it would still work.  Since that address is the address of the first char of the first array.