# How to initialize a const char array data member with C++?

Tags: c++

I have a question related to C++ class member initialization. The following code illustrates my question:

```
class ABCD
{
public:
    ABCD():ObjNum(3){};
    ~ABCD() {};
     static const  unsigned char getByte[8];
     const int ObjNum;


};

const unsigned char ABCD::getByte[8] = {
    'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'
};

int main() 
{
     ABCD test;
     cout<<test.getByte[3]<<endl;


     return 0;
}
```

The above codes work very well, but now if I do not set getByte[8] as static, how could I initialize the class? I have tried in this way, but failed:

```
class ABCD
{
public:
    ABCD():ObjNum(3),getByte('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')
    {

    };
    ~ABCD() {};
    const  unsigned char getByte[8];
     const int ObjNum;


};



int main() 
{
     ABCD test;
     cout<<test.getByte[3]<<endl;


     return 0;
}
```

The error I have obtained is as follows:

```
 error C2536: 'ABCD::ABCD::getByte' : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays
```

I understand the reason why I got the error, but I do not know how to fix it. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need a char array? It is better to use std::string. If you use C++11 you have also std::array that you can initialize with std::initializer_list.

Comment: What's wrong with the first code and why do you want to change it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878670/initializing-2d-array-in-class-constructor-in-c

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall There is nothing wrong with the first code, and it is just out of curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 you can initialize it like this:

```
ABCD() : ObjNum(3), getByte{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'} {}
```

If you are going to use C++11, though, it would be better to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as others have suggested in the comments. You could then define the array like:

```
const std::array<unsigned char, 8> getByte;
```

and initialize it in this way (note the double braces):

```
ABCD() : ObjNum(3), getByte{{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'}} {}
```

Comment: @GrzegorzHerman Indeed... the three of us just posted the same solution :)

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you can initialize arrays like this:

```
ABCD() : getByte { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h' }
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C++11 compatible compiler, you should be able to use like this:

```
ABCD():ObjNum(3),getByte{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'}
```

<strike>But if your compiler can't handle that you have to initialize the array manually in the constructor, either element by element or by having another array and then do e.g. `memcpy`.</strike>

**Edit:** If your compiler cant handle the C++11 syntax, you're pretty much out of luck. However, GCC since at least version 4.4, and also VC++2010, do handle it. So unless you have requirements forcing you to use "ancient" compilers it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to abandon C arrays. In C++ it is better to use std::string. In this case:

```
class A
{
public:
   A() : s("abcdefgh") {}

private:
   std::string s;
}
```

In C++11 you can use std::array and use std::initializer_list

```
class A
public:
   A() : s{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'} {}

private:
   std::array<8> s;
}
```

Comment: In embedded code the use of std::string comes with many problems.

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 you can change the member to be of type [boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/array.html) and initialize it in the constructor with a function that returns `boost::array<char,8>`.